# You should use prepared statements for accurate type mapping

Tags: cassandra

Why I get this error message ?

```
TypeError: Target data type could not be guessed, you should use prepared statements for accurate type mapping. Value: {
  full_name: 'Hshsbsjah',
  profile_image: 'NULL',
  phone: 'NULL',
}
```

Query:

```
              const query = `INSERT INTO users (user_id, email, password, user_details, user_since) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`;
              const result = await client.execute(query, [ userid, body.email, body.password, 
               { 
                  full_name: body.fullname, 
                  profile_image: 'NULL',
                  phone: 'NULL',
                }, 
                luxon.DateTime.now() ], { prepared: true });
```

```
user_details UDT:

CREATE TYPE user_information (
  full_name text,
  profile_image text,
  phone text
)
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. For more information, see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you no longer want this question here, you can delete it using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked on https://community.datastax.com/questions/11797/.

I've reached out to the driver devs at DataStax and I'm re-posting the answer by Bret McGuire here.

There is a typo in the code here:

```
luxon.DateTime.now() ], { prepared: true });
```

The correct property key is `prepare` instead of `prepared`. Cheers!